# Mac- How to create a setup for my java application to run on MAC

Tags: java, macos

I have created a dmg file which will open a window and a icon is visible, if I double-click on the icon, the application will run fine but I want to make the application ask the user the location to install and then install it there. Also when the application is running the dock icon is a java icon, but I want to add a custom icon there. Please tell me how to do these both. I am very much new to Mac.

I found the following code on SO to create dmg file

```
<plugin>
<groupId>sh.tak.appbundler</groupId>
    <artifactId>appbundle-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>xxxx</mainClass>
        <!--
            For example
            <jrePath>/foo/bar/jre1.8.0_112.jre</jrePath>
        -->
        <jrePath>xxxx</jrePath>
        <generateDiskImageFile>true</generateDiskImageFile>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>bundle</goal>
                </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
```

Comment: You will do better here if you have an attempt yourself and post the code you have tried. People here will not likely write the code for you, but rather will provide you with guidance on how to fix any errors you have in your code. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Alan Thank you for the tip, but I found a way to add the custom icon part using iconset for mac but I am still not able to install the application on Mac, I just give an .app file, by double-clicking on it the application is running fine.